# Pull multiple rows of data from one place in spreadsheet to another based on a condion

Tags: iwork-numbers, iwork

I have an iWork Numbers *(3.2 - 1861)* sheet with a list of people with the following structure:

```
|     Name    | Age  |         Email      | Condition |
|     Bart    |  12  | test@test.com      |     1     |
|     Marge   |  40  | marge@simsosn.sim  |     2     |
|     Lisa    |  8   | lisa@simsosn.sim   |     1     |
```

Naturally the amount of data is way larger, making the manual sorting impossible.

I need to sort these people into different groups based on the condition column, for example Bart and Lisa would belong to the first group, Marge to the second and so on.

I tried by using `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP` and `LOOKUP` functions and different combinations thereof but nothing seems to return *all* the values, these functions seem to return only 1 value at a time instead of the entire list of people matching the criteria.

If that description explaination is too convoluted I can explain by answering any questions you may have.

Comment: Including your reason for wanting to pull rows to another location might allow answers that would solve your initial issue.

Comment: I believe the: `I need to sort these people into different groups based on the condition column` answers that.

Comment: I was asking because this question appears like it might be an [xy problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Knowing if you are moving data for calculation, exporting, printing, or other purposes can help. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It is for sorting purposes. These people need to be sorted into groups on a separate sheet as these sheets will later be printed. It could be done by manually sorting all the entries and then copy-pasting the results, but that's clearly unefficient, hence the question if it can be done automatically with a Numbers function.